# R: incorporate warning message text into plot after filtering data.frame

Tags: r, text, plot, dataframe

I am filtering a data.frame `dat` and deleting rows which have duplicated `YEARs` in `REFERENCE_YEAR` in the following way:

```
dat <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2") , SURVEY_YEAR =c(1947,1958,1978,1987,1963,1991,2004,1993), REFERENCE_YEAR=c(1934,1947,1974,1947,1944,1987,1993,1987), VALUE=c(10,15,13,20,-2,7,12,-19))

    dat
       NAME SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
    1 NAME1        1947           1934    10
    2 NAME1        1958           1947    15
    3 NAME1        1978           1974    13
    4 NAME1        1987           1947    20
    5 NAME2        1963           1944    -2
    6 NAME2        1991           1987     7
    7 NAME2        2004           1993    12
    8 NAME2        1993           1987   -19

require(dplyr)
    dat <- dat %>%
        arrange(REFERENCE_YEAR) %>%
        mutate(gap = SURVEY_YEAR - REFERENCE_YEAR) %>%
        arrange(REFERENCE_YEAR, gap) %>%
        group_by(NAME, REFERENCE_YEAR) %>%
        filter(gap == gap[1]) %>%
        arrange(NAME,REFERENCE_YEAR)
```

After that I am plotting this data for each group (defined by `NAME`) into single graphs.

My Problem: Since I have to delete some data in the step above and this doesn't represent the correct data in the end, I am now looking for a way to incorporate a `text()` to plot into the graphs if data got deleted in the step above (something like a warning message in each graph) if not a normal plot should be generated. Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're after:

```
dat <- dat %>% group_by(NAME) %>% 
              mutate(count=n()) %>%   #Length of NAME
              arrange(REFERENCE_YEAR) %>% 
              mutate(gap = SURVEY_YEAR - REFERENCE_YEAR) %>% 
              arrange(REFERENCE_YEAR, gap) %>% 
              group_by(NAME, REFERENCE_YEAR) %>% 
              filter(gap == gap[1]) %>% 
              arrange(NAME,REFERENCE_YEAR) %>% 
              group_by(NAME) %>% 
              mutate(count.n=n()) %>%  #Length of NAME after deleting duplicates
              as.data.frame()

dat$inc <- ifelse(dat$count==dat$count.n, "complete", "incomplete")

dat %>% ggplot(., aes(x=SURVEY_YEAR, y=VALUE, group=NAME)) + geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label = inc), x=1960, y=4)
```

Comment: great. how would you incorporate it in baseR?

Comment: Ah sorry, since you were using dplyr I was assuming ggplot, don't know much about base R plots, so I'm afraid I can't help with that :/

Comment: no worries. I solved it by using mtext() or also title() in my plot command. thanks for your answer!